# Adding Multiple value in Tooltips in ChartJS charts

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have created a Multiple line Line chart using the ChartJS library on Laravel. It has two line. I want to add percentage data to my Line Chart **Tooltips** for each xLabel. But I am not able to use it in this wrapper. Could you help me out?

> Example: Line: data (percent_data)%

Below code is giving only the first element on my Charts Tooltips

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myLineChart");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: label,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Line",
      data: data,
      percent_data: per_data_from_html,
    }],
  },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
          var datasetLabel = chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
          return datasetLabel + ': ₹ ' + number_format(tooltipItem.yLabel)+' ('+ (chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].percent_data[tooltipItem.datasetIndex]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: will you please share a sample of `label` and `data`?

Comment: @WhiteHat, Thanks for your concern. I got the solution now. But I will still share my `label` and `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing parameter passing through `percent_data` array from `percent_data[tooltipItem.datasetIndex]` to `percent_data[tooltipItem.index]`.

```
tooltips: {
  enabled: true,
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
      var datasetLabel = chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
      return datasetLabel + ': ₹ ' + chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index] + ' (' + chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].percent_data[tooltipItem.index] + ')%';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is giving me the same percent_data while hovering in each point.

Comment: change the return into this =>

return datasetLabel + ': ₹ ' + chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index] + ' (' + chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].percent_data[tooltipItem.index] + ')%';

Comment: Thanks It is working for me. But I am curious to know what was the issue.

Comment: we changed **datasetIndex => index** while passing parameter to `percent_data`